# Prompted to enter system lock PIN code to unlock Mac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, activation-lock

A former terminated employee Fedex'ed us his company Macbook Air. When we turn it on we get this screen you see in the photo below. We do not have this 6 digit "system pin", never set it up, and are unsure how to re-format it. I've never seen this before.

> Enter your system lock PIN code to unlock this Mac.
>   Account Locked.

**We do have proof of purchase** from Apple for this computer and as I understand all Apple stores are closed now. Can anyone advise what can be done to unlock this laptop?

[image]

Comment: I, uh, don't think you can do anything—that would defeat the point of the PIN. You need to reach out to the former employee, or call Apple.

Comment: This is the importance of having good, solid employment contracts in place *before* things like this occur. I counsel many small businesses about mitigating risks like this; lots you can do technologically and lots you can do just by putting pen to paper. I’m staying hopeful that this doesn’t turn into an expensive lesson.

Comment: By the way. Love the avatar. I was a huge fan of *Battle of the Planets* when I was a kid.

Comment: @Allan yep - one of my favorites too.

Comment: And we do have contracts. This is a pure act of foul play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only two options:

1. Convince your former terminated employee to provide the 6 digit PIN. If you have a legal department or legal consult, they may be able to provide additional convincing with threat of a civil suit.
2. Schedule an in-person service appointment with an Apple Store or Apple Authorized Service Provider. Bring your Mac to the appointment, and bring your original receipt or invoice as proof of purchase. (apple.com - [How to set a firmware password on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204455)) If you choose this option, then *you better hurry* because Apple says "You can look up your passcode for a limited time".

Although first-party Apple Stores are closed right now because of the [2019 coronavirus pandemic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019%E2%80%9320_coronavirus_pandemic), some Authorized Apple Service Providers are still open. You can find one here: https://getsupport.apple.com/

---

This happened because your former employee attached an iCloud account to the Mac, enabled the [Find my Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204756) feature, and then initiated a remote lock sequence from iCloud. The lock status is stored in the system firmware, and cannot be bypassed even by replacing the boot disk.

Apple has a great page showing [all the possible boot screens](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204156) for a modern Mac.

Answer (score -2):

You have to get to inside the macbook then get the hardrive out, Access the hardrive from another PC and find the code from there.

Comment: That's not going to work for many reasons - the drive on an air is not removable. The PIN is not on the drive it's in the firmware.